# Mondegreens for normal speech - is there a specific word for them?

Tags: single-word-requests

I know that the term "mondegreen" (the term used for mishearing a word, coined by author Sylvia Wright when she famously misheard a lyric in The Bonny Earl of Murray) can technically be used for any misheard word, but I found myself wondering lately: does anyone know of a specific term used to describe misheard words outside of song lyrics?

To be clear, I mean if, say, you said to someone

> You can't carry that, you have a bad back.

And they thought you said

> You can't carry that, you have a backpack.

I haven't been able to find any other terms in my online research, but I'm really curious as to whether there is one. Have at it, StackExchange!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***[Otosis](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/otosis)*** conveys the meaning you are referring to:

> - mishearing or misinterpretation of spoken sounds, also an  alteration in word forms due to it.

(M-W)

[Origin](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/otosis):

> - Mid 19th cent. ***From ancient Greek ὠτ-, οὖς ear + [-osis](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/-osis?q=osis%20).***

(ODO)

Comment: And now I have a new word to annoy my wife with! That'll do nicely, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

According to Grammarist Sarah Belliston, the word you're looking for is eggcorn. See http://grammarist.com/mondegreens/.